# Interactive Data Language - Heap Buffer Overflow

Tags: heap-memory, buffer-overflow, idl-programming-language

I am trying to get IDL command line (v8.3) to work on OSX (El Capitan). While the installation was successful, I get the following error every time I start the idl command line:

==1361==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x621000237500 at pc 0x000101f8d4cd bp 0x7fff5fbfa910 sp 0x7fff5fbfa0d0
WRITE of size 24932 at 0x621000237500 thread T0

How do I rectify this problem? Additionally, is this a program issue or an issue with my operating system? Please let me know if additional information is required (logs/snapshots/messages)

Comment: General tools installation problems are unlikely to be answered (or helpful in the future) on SO. Asking supporters of the tool directly may be better option. Or maybe it can be on-topic/answered on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219803/grep-command-not-found) (due to OSX) or SuperUser.com

Comment: I believe that AddressSanitizer is a third-party tool that isn't directly part of either El Capitan or IDL. How are you starting the IDL command line? Have you tried starting it directly from the Mac terminal after running the appropriate idl_setup script? Finally, you should check your environment variables to make sure that your $PATH isn't set to something strange.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Thank you for your reply! I shall try requesting help from more appropriate forums.

Comment: @ChrisTorrence: I installed IDL using a .pkg file which created icons/shortcuts in the Applications folder. 

I cannot start idl from the terminal (idl command not found), my path variable is this: 
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin

However, upon starting IDL from Applications, XQUARTZ opens with the Heap-Buffer-Overflow error. 

Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ChrisTorrence: I was using XQuartz 2.7.9 (Beta version). Uninstalling it and reinstalling a stable of release of XQuartz seemed to resolve the issue. 

Additionally, I included the path "/Applications/.../bin/idl" to .bash_profile. I am able to start idl from the terminal.

Thank you for your help!